# how to isolate yellow part of the picture and make black other parts?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

This is the image:

[image: This is the image]

I want to turn all the colours to black except yellow and tried this code but showing an error can anyone please help?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread('Screenshot 2022-04-10 at 10.02.19 AM.png',1)
if(img.any() == [255, 255, 0]):
   cv.imshow('image',img);

else:
   ret , thresh1 = cv.threshold(img,500,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY);
cv.imshow("Timg",thresh1);
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error is showing for the if conditional statement.
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: just use `inRange` -- and your use of numpy is wrong. `(img == [255,255,0]).any()`

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**  TLDR;

1. Convert image to LAB color space
2. Otsu Threshold over b-component
3. Mask the result over the original image in BGR color space

**Code**

```
# read the image in BGR
img = cv2.imread("image_path", 1)

# convert image to LAB color space
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# store b-component
b_component = lab[:,:,2]
```

[image]

```
# perform Otsu threshold
ret,th = cv2.threshold(b_component, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image]

```
# mask over original image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = th)
```

[image]

**Details**

Why did I do this?

The [LAB color space](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space) contains 3 channels:

- *L-component*: highlights brightness value
- *a-component*: represents color values between green and magenta
- *b-component*: represents color values between blue and yellow

Since your image comprised of blue, magenta and yellow, I opted for LAB color space.  And specifically the b-component because it highlights yellow color

Comment: @jraj157 You have posted a question based on the final result of this question. Did this answer help you at all?

Comment: yes thanks for your help it helped and i tried the code this way. 

img = cv.imread('/Users/jagnyarajpatnaik/Desktop/Modules_py/Screenshot 2022-04-10 at 10.02.19 AM.png',1)

img_HSV = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # converting to HSV color range
img_threshold = cv.inRange(img_HSV,(25,100,100),(35,255,255)) # making the mask based on hsv range
k1 = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = img_threshold) # converting the white color to yellow by bitwise


cv.imshow('image',img)
cv.imshow("Timg",k1)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: hope the HSV conversion worked

Comment: yeah first converting it into hsv and then masking it to form the black and white img of 0,1 matrix then using bitwise_and operator made me do it. Can u please check the second question that i posted.

Comment: @jraj157 I saw your code. You are going in the right direction by finding lines. Make sure you find 4 strong lines and then find angles between each pair of them

Comment: i posted an answer i found all the four line by houghman transform but i m not getting the intersection point like while i am trying to put the text ,the angle at the intersection point it is not showing off so can you please help in this?