# Unable to read image text with python tesseract and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, captcha

I am trying read text from this

[image: this image]

using Python with OpenCV. However, it is not able to read it.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img=cv.imread(file_path,0)

img = cv.medianBlur(img,5)
ret,th1 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)

th2 =cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
    cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

th3 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
    cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)',
    'Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']

images = [img, th1, th2, th3]

for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working on the grayscale image, working on saturation channel of the HSV color space makes the subsequent steps easier.

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path_to_captcha)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
s_component = hsv[:,:,1]
```

`s_component`
[image]

Next, apply a Gaussian blur of appropriate kernel size and sigma value, and later threshold.

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(s_component,(7,7), 7)
ret,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

`th3`
[image]

Next, finding contours in the image above and preserving those above a certain area threshold in the `black` image variable which will be used as mask later on.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th3, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
black = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)

for contour in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) >600 :
        cv2.drawContours(black, [contour], 0, 255, -1)
```

`black`
[image]

Using the `black` image variable as mask over the threshold image

```
res = cv2.bitwise_and(th3, th3, mask = black)
```

`res`
[image]

Finally, applying morphological thinning to the above result

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
erode = cv2.erode(res, kernel, iterations=1)
```

`erode`
[image]

The end result is not what you expect. You can try experimenting different morphology operations prior to drawing contours as well.

**EDIT**

You can perform distance transform on the above image and use the result:

```
dist = cv2.distanceTransform(res, cv2.DIST_L2, 3)
dst = cv2.normalize(dist, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

`dst`
[image]